# Nested ForEach with afterRender callbacks in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

What i want: access to a custom afterRender from my nested foreach.

What i have:

I am building a collapsible list of podcasts that each have multiple categories. What i currently have is the list of podcasts being generated using foreach, with a categories element inside being generated using another foreach.

```
<div id="content-programs">
        <!-- content -->
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-bind="foreach: { data: entries }">
            <div class="entry" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>

                <b>Author:</b> <span data-bind="text: author"></span><p>
                <b>Published:</b> <span data-bind="text: publishedDate"></span><p>

                <p>
                    <span data-bind="text: contentSnippet"></span>
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: link}" >Full Story</a>               
                </p>

                <b>Categories:</b>
                <div data-bind="foreach: categories">
                    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
                </div>          

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My request is pretty simple actually, i just want to comma delimit the categories. I can do this on the data, or something similar, but im also exploring knockout, and interested in what it can offer.

Here is what i've tried:

```
        feed = ko.mapping.fromJS(response.responseData.feed);
        ko.applyBindings
        (
            {
                entries:        feed.entries,                       
                arCategories:   
                function(categories, data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                }                   
            }
        );
```

HTML

```
<b>Categories:</b>
    <div data-bind="foreach: {data: categories, afterRender: arCategories}">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are inside of a context of a `foreach` you need to use `$parent` to access your `arCategories` method which is declared one "level up".

```
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: categories, afterRender: $parent.arCategories}">
   <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RTU8c/1/).

See also [Note 2: Using $index, $parent, and other context properties](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_2_using_index_parent_and_other_context_properties) and the [Binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) pages in the documenation for further information.

Sidenote:

If you only want a comma delimited list you can just use the [`array.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
<div data-bind="text: categories.join()"></div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vzWd/).

Comment: Confirmed this works, and thanks for the documentation link. I feel like i have scoured that page, but the disconnect between the markup and js makes it tough to fill the gaps. Thanks!

Comment: also, thanks for the .join comment. Since i have mapped my arrays already, i had to use categories().join(), but it works swimmingly.